# How to add a workbook sheet into another workbook

Tags: excel, rpa, uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-activity

Here is the excel "db" and excel "scrape".

[image: excel "db" and excel "scrap"]

[image: four sheets in the same excel (scrap, ai, bd, and eb)]

And I want to achieve like this, add the sheet "scrap" into excel "db", i.e. four sheets in the same excel (scrap, ai, bd, and eb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying sheets from one workbook to another is not hard to be solved. You will only need a `Excel Application Scope` and a `Copy Sheet` activity:

[image: copy sheets]

So all you need is the file path where the source Excel is. And the destination Excel file path. And the name of the sheet.